# Change $\inf$ order

Tags: analysis, optimization

Is it true that if $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $g : X \times Y \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ then
$$ \inf_{x \in X} \left( f(x) - \inf_{y \in Y} g(x,y) \right) = \inf_{x \in X}  \sup_{y \in Y} \left( f(x) - g(x,y) \right) \text{ ?} $$

Is there some sort of idea to treat this kind of expressions? Like for example is it true that
$$ \inf_{x \in X} \left( f(x) - \inf_{y \in Y} \left( g(x,y) - \inf_{p \in X} g(p,y) \right)  \right) = \inf_{x \in X} \sup_{y \in Y} \inf_{p \in X} \left( f(x) -  g(x,y) + g(p,y) \right)    \text{ ?}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is always true that $\inf A = - \sup (-A)$.

Hence $\inf_{x \in X} \left( f(x) - \inf_{y \in Y} g(x,y) \right) = \inf_{x \in X} \left( f(x) + \sup_{y \in Y} (-g(x,y) )\right)$.

Since $f$ is a not a function of $y$, we have

$\inf_{x \in X} \left( f(x) + \sup_{y \in Y} (-g(x,y) )\right) =\inf_{x \in X} \left( \sup_{y \in Y} (f(x)-g(x,y) )\right)$

For the second example, following the same rules:
\begin{eqnarray}
\inf_{x \in X} \left( f(x) - \inf_{y \in Y} \left( g(x,y) - \inf_{p \in X} g(p,y) \right)  \right) &=& \inf_{x \in X} \left( f(x) - \inf_{y \in Y} \left( g(x,y) + \sup_{p \in X} (-g(p,y)) \right)  \right) \\
&=&\inf_{x \in X} \left( f(x) - \inf_{y \in Y} \sup_{p \in X} \left( g(x,y) -g(p,y)\right)  \right) \\
&=&\inf_{x \in X} \left( f(x) + \sup_{y \in Y} (-\sup_{p \in X} \left( g(x,y) -g(p,y)\right))  \right) \\
&=&\inf_{x \in X} \left( f(x) + \sup_{y \in Y} (\inf_{p \in X} \left( g(p,y) -g(x,y)\right))  \right) \\
&=&\inf_{x \in X} \left( \sup_{y \in Y} (\inf_{p \in X} \left( f(x) +g(p,y) -g(x,y)\right))  \right) \\
&=&\inf_{x \in X} \sup_{y \in Y} \inf_{p \in X} \left( f(x) +g(p,y) -g(x,y)  \right)
\end{eqnarray}

Answer (score 0):

Most obvious, you have
$$
-\sup_{y\in Y}g(y) = \inf_{y\in Y}(-g(y)),
$$
as well as, for some constant $C$,
$$
C + \sup_{y\in Y}g(y) = \sup_{y\in Y}(C+g(y)).
$$
Combining these, we get your first statement.

Unfortunately, I'm not sure what you mean by your second question.